# How to return a list of a person's friend with the most friends

Tags: java

I am supposed to make a method that returns a person's friend, with the most friends. I have two classes: Person and Network. It is supposed to return a person (the friend of the person who has the most friends).
I have ArrayList imported, but that is it. I can use loop, stream or Lambda.

I suppose I could run a map, then max (reduce) but I'm not sure how to do this. Struggling to find a "recipe"/explanation for the use of max in this contest.

This is what I have, and I have no idea what I am doing. Sorry if my explanation is unclear. Can someone help me?

```
private ArrayList<Person> friends;

public Person mostConnectedFriend() {  
    int count = 0;

    for (Person person : friends) {
        if (friends.size() >= count) {
            return person;
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: `return friends.stream().max(Comparator.comparingInt(p -> p.getFriends().size()));`

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question

Answer (score 0):

You want to know which friend is most popular.

If you have a List of friends, you want the one that has the largest List of friends.

The function you wrote won't do it.

This will do better.  I left something for you to do.

```
public Person mostConnectedFriend() {  
    // TODO: This is the function you have to have
    int maxFriendCount = ?;
    for (Person friend: friends) {
        if (friend.getFriends().size() == maxFriendCount) {
            return friend;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Why use two iterations when one will do?

Comment: I couldn't agree more.  Your lambda is excellent.  I thought it'd be better to write it out because the OP seemed young and inexperienced.

Comment: Forget about lambdas, why not use a single loop?

Comment: I decided to err on the side of writing code that would be most easily understood by a novice programmer.  The OP is new to SO and was troubled by what would be a simple problem.  brt

Comment: Who cares about single loop, lambdas, or efficiency?  I know that it's an O(n) problem, but anyone who's studied algorithm complexity knows that it won't matter for small values of N.  Nobody will have a list of friends long enough for this to be a problem, unless you're Kim Kardashian.

Comment: I wasn't really going for efficiency. It just seemed more straightforward to me.

Comment: Think back to when you were first learning Java or programming in general.  I'm certain your first thoughts about most straightforward have changed since then.  If not, then count yourself lucky.

Comment: @shmosel, if you have a better one, or at least if you think so, It might be a good idea to posting it as an alternative solution. This answer works, it's just we can't always expect answers to be the most effective ones. Asking someone to change his/her answers relatively to our own ways is IMO , a bit rude.

Comment: @shmosel actually posted the best answer as a comment.  I'm fine with that.  I agree wholeheartedly that it's the best answer.  I only disagree that a new programmer will appreciate its elegance as much as they might in the future.  Thank you for defending and upvoting me.  I'll admit that I get tired of argumentative, "I know better" comments.  By all means post your own.

Comment: @Plain_Dude_Sleeping_Alone I didn't ask anyone to change their answer. I was just trying to understand why he took the approach he did. And I'm perfectly content with his response.